# 8 ball pools, foul rules when only 8 ball is on the table?

Tags: rules, pool

What happens if I've only 8 ball remaining, my opponent has his category object balls remaining. I called a pocket for 8 ball but didn't pocket it and it still remains on the table. 
Will my opponent get a ball in hand foul and can put cue ball anywhere on the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your opponent can't put cue ball anywhere.

The rules says:

> The shooter fails to strike one of their own object balls (or the 8
>   ball, if all of said object balls are already pocketed) with the cue
>   ball, before other balls (if any) are contacted by the cue ball.

If these fouls are made, the ball can be placed anywhere on the table to prevent a player from making a purposeful foul to disadvantage the other player. 
So, the only way your opponent has is if you do not hit the 8 ball.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a legal shot before the 8 ball, it's legal when you are on the 8 ball.
In other words, the 8 ball doesn't change the rules for a foul. 
The only difference I've ever seen is the APA rule, that says a scratch (and only a scratch, no other kind of foul) when playing the 8 ball will lose the game.